# Using Python for Android with theano import, gives IOError: [Errno 21]

Tags: android, python, kivy

I have a Python-Kivy app that I want to make available to Android. The app uses Theano and Numpy. I get the following adb logcat when running app on an Android device:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):

I/python  (24492):    File "main.py", line 19, in <module>

I/python  (24492):      from theano import function

I/python  (24492):    File "/data/data/org.example.AppName/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>

I/python  (24492):      from theano.configdefaults import config

I/python  (24492):    File "/data/data/org.example.AppName/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/configdefaults.py", line 1486, in <module>

I/python  (24492):      "platform": platform.platform(),

I/python  (24492):    File "/home/user-name/.local/share/python-for-android/build/other_builds/python2/armeabi/python2/python-install/lib/python2.7/platform.py", line 1575, in platform

I/python  (24492):    File "/home/user-name/.local/share/python-for-android/build/other_builds/python2/armeabi/python2/python-install/lib/python2.7/platform.py", line 163, in libc_ver

I/python  (24492):  IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/data/data/org.example.AppName/files'

I/python  (24492): Python for android ended.
```

I don't know how to proceed, or if it's possible to import Theano in Android. The Kivy app works on Linux and Windows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The actual reason for the error is that platform.py makes an incorrect assumption about the location of the Python executable, and gets confused because it's a directory. In reality, there is no executable because Python is being run via a short C program. I'm not sure if there's something you're supposed to do to make the platform module work in this case, but it might be useful to follow up. However, in this case if the existing question answer is correct about Theano not supporting Android, that may not be useful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theano doesn't support android. You could use [TensorFlow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow) or create a webservice and make http request from your app to ask the service to do the job for you.